# javascript native prototype: extend, add and overwrite methods?

Tags: javascript, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

How can I extend a prototype and add new methods into it? For instance I want to extend **Shape** (superclass) into a subclass - **Rectangle**. I am extending it because I want to use the methods in **Shape**, but **add more** methods (and **overwrite** some **Shape**'s methods as well) in **Rectangle**.

But I **can't** use/ access the methods in **Shape** anymore after adding methods in **Rectangle**,

```
// Shape - superclass
function Shape() {
  this.x = 0;
  this.y = 0;
}

// superclass method
Shape.prototype.move = function(x, y) {
  this.x += x;
  this.y += y;
  console.info('Shape moved.');
};

// Rectangle - subclass
function Rectangle() {
  Shape.call(this); // call super constructor.
}

// subclass extends superclass
Rectangle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype);
Rectangle.prototype.constructor = Rectangle;

Rectangle.prototype = {
    jump : function(){
        return 'Shape jumped';
    }
};

var rect = new Rectangle();

console.log('Is rect an instance of Rectangle? ' + (rect instanceof Rectangle)); // true
console.log('Is rect an instance of Shape? ' + (rect instanceof Shape)); // true
rect.move(1, 1); // TypeError: rect.move is not a function
```

The result I am after,

```
// Outputs, 'Shape moved.'
```

Any ideas what have I missed?

Comment: You aren't running the code you posted. `rect instanceof Shape` returns false (because *Rectangle.prototype* no longer inherits from *Shape.prototype*).

Comment: you're right. my mistakes...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are overwriting `Rectangle.prototype` here:

```
Rectangle.prototype = {
    jump : function(){
        return 'Shape jumped';
    }
};
```

You should add to it instead:

```
Rectangle.prototype.jump = function(){
  return 'Shape jumped';
}
```